# Gauss-Seidel and bound of iterations using the residual norm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I would like to find the least $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$Res=\frac{\|b-Ax^{(k)}\|}{\|b\|}\leq \epsilon$$ for given $\epsilon$, when using the Gauss-Seidel iteration. I calculated the norm (arbitrary) of the numerator up to a point and reached this result:
$$\|[I +(D+L)(B^k-I)(D+L)^{-1}] b\|$$ where $D=4Ι$, $Β=-(D+L)^{-1}U$, $L=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0\cr 1&0&0\cr 1&1&0\end{matrix}\right)$, $U=L^T$ και $b=[6,6,6]^T$

Could anyone lend a hand? It doesn't seem like it can get any simpler, but I want to avoid any unnecessary computations of matrix products. Do I have to use another upper bound of the fraction to do the job?